# Navigating menus using buttons on Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, c, genuino

I have made a very short version of my code. It has the basic problem I am facing. I explain my code and problem below.

```
#include <Adafruit_RGBLCDShield.h>
#include <utility/Adafruit_MCP23017.h>
Adafruit_RGBLCDShield lcd = Adafruit_RGBLCDShield();

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2); //format of display
}

int menu = 0;
int subMenu = 99;
void loop() {

  uint8_t buttons = lcd.readButtons();

  lcd.setCursor(0,0);

  if (menu == 0) {
  lcd.print("Select menu option");
    if (buttons & BUTTON_SELECT) {
      lcd.clear();
      menu = 99;
      subMenu = 1;
    }
  }

  if (subMenu == 1) {
    lcd.print("in sub menu 1");
    if (buttons & BUTTON_SELECT) {
       lcd.clear();
       lcd.setCursor(0,1);
       lcd.print("shouldnt happen");
    }
  }
}
```

I am setting a variable `menu`, which will keep track of what main menu I am on, and a `subMenu`, which keeps track of what sub-menu I am on.

The default value of `menu` (0) prints on the LCD "Select Menu Option".

When pressing SELECT, the LCD is cleared. The `menu` is being set to an unknown number, so that it doesn't print anything, and `subMenu` is set to 1.

If `subMenu` is equal to 1 (which it will be if the user chooses presses SELECT), the LCD prints "in sub menu 1".

Inside this, if the button SELECT is clicked, it should print "shouldnt happen".

The issue I am facing is that when clicking SELECT for entering the menu 1, the SELECT is also carried out to the sub-menu, so instead of waiting for a second key press to confirm going into the sub menu, it goes straight into it.

This makes sense because it is check that SELECT has been pressed, prints a new page, with the button SELECT still having been pressed, so it validated the condition for key press in the sub menu as well.

**The user input to LCD display response should be the following:**

Select menu option -> presses SELECT -> in sub menu 1 -> presses SELECT -> shouldnt happen

**Currently however, it is like this:**

Select menu option -> presses SELECT -> in sub menu 1 shouldnt happen

How can I make it so that these key presses only act on the menu on which they are?

Thanks, let me know if something confuses you, I can explain in more details

Comment: Would still love to read any tips or help regarding these multi-level buttons. Thanks!

Comment: In your posted code I don't see you changing `menu` anywhere, except for setting it to 99 if it is zero.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about built-in buttons, however on my projects I always add a debounce feature to any buttons.  Adjust this to your uses. If there's any issues let me know and I'll test it properly as I'm not at my programming workstation to fully test at the moment.

For example:

```
// Updated to include if statements and copy/pasted version of successfully
// compiled version.

// Had to use LiquidCrystal library as I don't have the AdaFruit Display libraries.
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
//

int menu = 0, subMenu = 99, debounce = 200;
unsigned long pMillis = 0, cMillis;

void setup(){
  lcd.begin(16,2);
};

void loop(){
  cMillis = millis(); // sets cMillis to current millis()
  //uint8_t buttons = lcd.readButtons();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  if(cMillis >= (pMillis + debounce)){
    if (menu == 0) {
      lcd.print("Select menu option");
      /*if (buttons & BUTTON_SELECT) {
       *  lcd.clear();
       *  menu = 99;
       *  subMenu = 1;
       *  };
       */
    };
    if (subMenu == 1) {
      lcd.print("in sub menu 1");
      /*if (buttons & BUTTON_SELECT) {
       *  lcd.clear();
       *  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
       *  lcd.print("shouldnt happen");
       *  };
       */
    };
  pMillis = cMillis; // sets pMillis to cMillis for the next iteration of the loop()
  };
  // I always put something similar to this at the end 
  // to make sure that when millis() cycles back to 0 
  // pMillis is reset to less than cMillis.
  if(cMillis < pMillis){
    pMillis = cMillis; // sets pMillis to cMillis for the next iteration of the loop()
  };
};
```

Edit/Update:  This compiles fine using the standard LiquidCrystal library, I am unable to test the AdaFruit display as I don't have one.  If this still doesn't work, I'll upload it to the Arduino when I get back and see what's up.

New test:

```
// Your libraries here

int menu = 0,
    subMenu = 99,
    debounce = 200;

unsigned long pMillis = 0,
          cMillis;

void setup(){
  lcd.begin(16,2);
}

void loop(){
  cMillis = millis(); // sets cMillis to current millis()
  //uint8_t buttons = lcd.readButtons();

  if(buttons & BUTTON_SELECT){ // I used "if(digitalRead(buttonPin) == HIGH){ ... }"
    if(cMillis >= (pMillis + debounce)){
      //I'd normally put counter/menu logic in here for the different buttons, for example:
      //"subMenu += 1;
      // if(subMenu >= totalSubMenus) { subMenu = 0; };"
      subMenu = 1;
      pMillis = cMillis;
    }
  }

  if(menu == 0){
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Select Menu Option");
    menu = 99;
  }
  if(subMenu == 1){
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("In Sub Menu 1");
  }

  if(cMillis < pMillis){
    pMillis = cMillis; // sets pMillis to cMillis for the next iteration of the loop()
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Here is my code implemented with your solution if you'd like to test it out. https://pastebin.com/0Uy3mspN

Comment: @JonGoe I've updated the original and added the setup() function in there too... I can test this properly later.  One thing, is "(buttons & BUTTON_SELECT)" correct? should it be an "&&" in there instead?  if there's still no joy, try a search of adding a debounce function.  I'll be about later if no one else has answered

Comment: No, the single & is correct. Ill be looking online for a debounce function. Looking foward to hear from you! Thanks

Comment: @JonGoe - Updated with successfully compiled version.  Unable to upload it to an Arduino at this moment, but I have the LCD and buttons already in the breadboard at home, and wired, as I was doing this a couple of days ago.

Comment: @JonGoe - one last thing.  you have subMenu = 1 in the first "if" statement, which then means the next "if(subMenu == 1)" statement will be true.  To test that, put "delay(1000);) after "submenu = 1" in the first if statement and see if the first text displays correctly.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was going for. When select a sub menu choice from the menu, the sub meny is accessed through verifying if the subMenuIndex matches a condition. If it does (meaning the sub menu is what the user wants to see), then this sub menu is shown.

I've adapted the code to use the AdaFruit library, but still no luck using the SELECT button independently.

Comment: @JonGoe - Ok, apologies, I did misread the last sentence of your question.  Debounce is always good to have anyway it can save a lot of headache.  I've not spent a huge time on bitwise/pointers ([&, |, ^](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/BitwiseAnd) and [&, *](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Pointer)) before, but it looks as if "(buttons & BUTTON_SELECT)" is always true, therefore always running through both "if" statements.  what happens if you add a "delay(1000)" in the end of the first and second if statements?

Comment: `if "(buttons & BUTTON_SELECT)"` will be true when the SELECT button is clicked. I am certain of this because in my actual program, I am using the same syntax with LEFT, RIGHT, UP and DOWN, and these are working fine. Adding a delay only delays when the printing of the message on the LCD. It pauses the program but doesn't affect the status of button pressed

Comment: @JonGoe - I've changed it to how I'd order things a little more, although personally I'd be using switch() and having separate functions.  But I can't tell from a small snippet, and could cause hours of further fun! :D